# Xcode - Get file from NSDocumentDirectory path

Tags: ios, xcode

I generated a multi page pdf from my web view and I would like to share the pdf file via an ActivityViewController. I only have the file path and dont know, how to access the file to let them share via the ActivityViewController.

```
CGRect origframe = webView.frame;
NSString *heightStr = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"]; // Get the height of our webView
int height = [heightStr intValue];

// Size of the view in the pdf page
CGFloat maxHeight   = 568;
CGFloat maxWidth    = webView.frame.size.width;
int pages = ceil(height / maxHeight);
// gets the total no:of pages needed in PDF

[webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, maxWidth, maxHeight)];

NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *pdfFileName = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mypdf.pdf"];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectZero, nil);

int i = 0;
for ( ; i < pages; i++)
{
    if (maxHeight * (i+1) > height)
    { // Check to see if page draws more than the height of the UIWebView
        CGRect f = [webView frame];
        f.size.height -= (((i+1) * maxHeight) - height);
        [webView setFrame: f];
    }

    // Specify the size of the pdf page
    CGRect PDFRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(PDFRect, nil);

    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // Move the context for the margins
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1, 1);
    // offset the webview content so we're drawing the part of the webview for the current page
    [[[webView subviews] lastObject] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, maxHeight * i) animated:NO];
    // draw the layer to the pdf, ignore the "renderInContext not found" warning.
    [webView.layer renderInContext:currentContext];
}
// all done with making the pdf
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
// Restore the webview and move it to the top.
[webView setFrame:origframe];
[[[webView subviews] lastObject] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO];
```

How can I share the finished file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put you file url into UIActivityViewController

```
NSString * title =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some title string", pdfFileName];
NSArray* pdfToShare = @[title];
UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:pdfToShare applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

UPDATE:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1547245-datawithcontentsofurl

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: pdfFileName options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    // make some stuff with pdf data
}
```

Comment: This does not work. I only get the file directory. Not the pdf file

Comment: check you pdfFileName in debug mode. could you give some info here

Comment: Well, pdfFileName only contains my path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FA9453C1-45BF-4A1C-B7GC-7881690926B6/Documents/mypdf.pdf

Comment: You can see at the end of line mypdf.pdf What is wrong?

Comment: I would like to have the file. not the name of the file

Comment: Which file do you want to have? you create a file which contains pdf of your page.

Comment: I want to have the file content. Not the file path... What should a user do with an internal file directory path?

Comment: Check update. And please write exact what you need, because in question you tell about sharing